# Erro ao obter ByteArray de arquivo.3gp no Android/Java

Tags: java, android, byte, encode

Estou tentando converter um arquivo de **audio.3gp** para string *Base64* e enviar para o servidor utilizando o Volley, mas pelo que sei, eu preciso transformar o **audio.3gp** em *ByteArray* e transformar esse *array* de bytes em string *base64*.

Eu não recebo nenhum tipo de erro ou aviso no compilador, apenas o retorno está difícil de entender...

Exemplo de retorno byte

```
[] = ������ ftyp3gp4��������isom3gp4���� �moov������lmvhd���������> ��
```

Meu código para transformar File em ByteArray

```
File file1 = new File(path);
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file1);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        while (fis.available() > 0) {
            bos.write(fis.read());
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    String msgDecode = new String(bytes);
    System.out.print("BYTES ==== " + msgDecode);
```

Já tenteia alterar o charset da saída, mas não resolveu...

Answer (score 0):

Isso é normal - nem todos os tipos de dados são criados para terem uma representação textual.

No caso, você está lidando com um tipo de arquivo binário - qualquer valor pode ter um valor de 0 até 255, que não necessariamente corresponde a um caractere imprimível, e mesmo que corresponda, não tem que ter nenhuma sequência que faça sentido.

Já a ideia da conversão para "base64" é justamente re-codificar esses dados, de forma que eles possam ser transmitidos usando 100% de caracteres imprimíveis - 
Isso garante que protocolos de rede e filtros pensados para tratar texto não vão intereferir com a natureza dos dados.

Se você imprimir seus dados depois de converte-los para Base64, vai ver que todos os caracteres são impressos com sucesso - mas a saída vai continuar não fazendo sentido algum - os dados simplesmente não estão codificados como texto.

**resumindo** Não tem nenhum erro até o ponto em que você está - faça agora a etapa de codificação em base64 e envio para o servidor, e não tente verificar se "está indo bem" olhando os dados impressos.